# What is: do if [ $i -nt ${LOG_DIR_PATH}/test ]

Tags: bash

What does `-nt` do for this case?

```
LOG_DIR_PATH=/home/users/chinboon/test-chinboon/logs/sandbox1

do if [ $i -nt ${LOG_DIR_PATH}/test ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-nt` flag checks if file `$i` has a more recent modification date than file `${LOG_DIR_PATH}/test`.

See `man 1 test` for all available flags.

I am pointing you to `man test` since

```
if [ $i -nt ${LOG_DIR_PATH}/test ]; then
   # SOMETHING
fi
```

is a shorthand for

```
if test $i -nt ${LOG_DIR_PATH}/test; then
   # SOMETHING
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [IBM DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test/index.html) the purpose if `-nt` is to

> Test if file1 is newer than file 2. The modification date is used for this and the next comparison.

So basically you're checking if the file whose filename is stored in `$i` is newer than the file with filename `${LOG_DIR_PATH}/test`.